# rails memcache dev vs production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, capistrano

I am using memcache for caching in my rails app and currently I have a dev and a production environment.

I would like to run the dev environment without caching so that I can debug more easily but I wanna enable the caching in production obviously. I am using github and capistrano for deployment.

Without doing a check at every statement where I can potentially dig into the cache, is there any way of handling this more gracefully or globally?

if env == 'dev'
  @post = Post.all
else
  //get @post from cache
end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider adding a "flush_all" some where in your capistrano deployment script.  This should help in removing "old" cache content for your capistrano development pushes.

You may also want to consider overloading/aliasing the get/set CACHE functions and just replacing the code where you are doing the caching.  I haven't seen a good implementation of this.

You may also want to overload the Rails.logger and add in display of the memcache code where you want it

```
Rails.logger.memcache_display = true
..
..
Rails.logger.memcache_display = false
```

This doesn't answer your question, but this can help make debuging more easy.

Comment: Sorry could you explain more about Rails.logger.memcache_display option? Where I have to put this code? Looks like exactly what I need. Tried that in configuration files and console. Always getting _undefined method `memcache_display=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)_.

Comment: Argh... I answered this a year ago, and I don't remember any more.  I think that when you enabled caching, Rails 2.3.5 would also diplay when memcache was accessed.  I think memcache_display turned it on and off...